# Parsing data in text into excel columns

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I want to parse the below portion of the text file such that the incremental numbers under "DVA" are placed into a column as a range of cells that I determine. I would like to do the same for the serial numbers starting with S in the second column, also in a range that I determine. There is a `|` delimeter between them, and I would like `DAU SNo.-C0` to be the string that I search for.

I am thinking: search for `DAU SNo.-C0`, then somehow skip two lines and copy what is underneath into Excel, parsing the data into two columns and determining the range of cells it should be placed in.

```
       DAU SNo.-C0
+-------------------------+
|DVA|          0          |
+-------------------------+
| 0 | S1050360701270      |
| 1 | S1050344701369      |
| 2 | S1050360701315      |
| 3 | S1021360701337      |
| 4 | S1050360701367      |
| 5 | S1050332701350      |
| 6 | S1050360701584      |
+-------------------------+
```

This is what I have: UPDATED

```
Do While i < UBound(strAll)
       If (InStr(1, strAll(i), "DAU SNo.-C0", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
          i = i + 4 'Skip 4 lines to get to first SN
          Do Until InStr(1, strAll(i), "+", vbTextCompare) > 0 'Loop until line includes "+"
             strSNO = Split(strAll(i), "|", -1, vbTextCompare)
             'put strSNO into next cell in column A
             i = i + 1
          Loop
       End If
    i = i + 1
    Loop
   Next
```

I have tried several ways of putting the split string into the next cell in the column but I can't get it to work. Everything words except the actual copying the value (where the comment is in the code). I verified that the rest works by printing the strSNO(1) and strSNO(2).

Any direction, explanation or code would be helpful.

Comment: Is the `>` part of the text file? I'm guessing not, but you will have to edit the question yourself to make sure I do not break anything.

Comment: No, they aren't. I removed them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you've found the line, use the VBA `Split` function, using `|` as a delimiter. It splits a string into an array.

Example: if you do this:

```
strTest = Split(">| 0 | S1050360701270", "|", -1, vbTextCompare)
```

it will come out like `strTest(1) = 0` , `strTest(2) = S1050360701270`.

You may also want to use `strAll = Split(objReadFile.ReadAll, vbCrLf, -1, vbTextCompare)` to bring the whole text file into VBA first (it's sometimes quicker), then using an integer variable to work through each line - it means you can skip a few lines when you find that "DAU SNo.-C0" string, rather than having to read each one.

======EDIT======

Try replacing the do loop in your code with something like this:

```
Dim strAll() As String, strSNO() As String, i As Integer
strAll = Split(objReadFile.ReadAll, vbCrLf, -1, vbTextCompare) 'Gets each line from file
i = LBound(strAll)
Do While i < UBound(strAll)
    If (InStr(1, strAll(i), "DAU SNo.-C0", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
        i = i + 4 'Skip 4 lines to get to first | 0 | S1050360701270 | line
        Do Until InStr(1, strAll(i), "+", vbTextCompare) > 0 'Loop until line includes "+"
            strSNO = Split(strAll(i), "|", -1, vbTextCompare)
            'This will add them to the next available row in A / B... change as needed
            Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Trim(strSNO(1))
            Range("B60000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Trim(strSNO(2))
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: I've looked at the split function. What I'd like is a method to use it to recursively do it for every a set number of lines beneath the identifier, and without knowing any of the values in the table.

Comment: This is a great piece of code. Unfortunately, it complained about the Dim statements "expected end of statement". Removing the "As String" and "As Integer" helped, but then I am getting a type mismatch on: `strAll = Split(objReadFile.ReadAll, vbCrLf, -1, vbTextCompare)`

Comment: Hmmm... I can't see why that would happen - try splitting the Dimensioning onto separate lines so `Dim strAll() as String` then `Dim strSNO() as String`. That should sort out the type mismatch

Comment: Any inclusion of "as string" or "as integer" causes a compilation error "expected end of statement". I believe this is because VBscript doesn't support declaring types? Without them I get a type mismatch, regardless of splitting the Dim statements.

Comment: Where are you running this code from? Is it in VBA or VBScript? My code was written for VBA... If you're doing it in VBScript, try removing the brackets from the end of the variable names.

Comment: From the command console using cscript.exe then the VBscript file. Your suggestion helped but I am running into errors in other lines that are probably a VBA/VBscript issue. I'll look into it further. Thanks a lot.